# How do I change TextBox.Text without losing the binding in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In a WPF application, I am creating a setting window to customize keyboard shortcuts.

In the textboxes, I handle the KeyDown event and convert the Key event to a human readable form (and also the form in which I want to have my data).

The text box is declared like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ShortCutText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

and in the event handler, I tried using both

```
(sender as TextBox).Text = "...";
```

and

```
(sender as TextBox).Clear();
(sender as TextBox).AppendText("...");
```

In both of these cases, the binding back to the viewmodel does not work, the viewmodel still contains the old data and does not get updated.
Binding in the other direction (from viewmodel to the textbox) works fine.

Is there a way I can edit the TextBox.Text from code without using the binding?
Or is there an error somewhere else in my process?

Comment: Ideally you should update this value in your model which will automatically reflect changes in textboxes as you are using MVVM.

Comment: Try to add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding

Comment: I know this is an old question by now but one thing that people seem to be ignoring here is if you have a control's property bound to another control (Say a list of check boxes that are all checked or unchecked by a parent checkbox). There may be nothing in the VM to help you here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var box = sender as TextBox;
// Change your box text..

box.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

This should force your binding to update.

Comment: With using UpdateTarget(), it actually does no update at all, even the textbox keeps the old value.

Comment: Some answers to require still some thinking.. seeing you used the same code I did, except I didn't adjust the text in between.. I consider this to be the right answer?

Comment: I did give you a +1 since you are the only one who helped.

Comment: Same in Xaml: `<TextBox Text="{Binding ShortCutText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Answer (score 3):

Don't change the Text property - change what you are binding to.

Comment: Why should the textbox have a reference to the viewmodel itself? I dont want to do any casting to my specific type, thats why I used two-way binding.

Comment: It shouldn't.  Don't refer to the textbox.  Whatever logic you have to update the text, it shouldn't know about the textbox.

Comment: Updating a viewmodel property programamtically should be done in the viewmodel ideally

Comment: What if the user entered invalid data into the TextBox that cannot be written to the ViewModel, so the text in the TextBox cannot come from the ViewModel but must be corrected first?

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick:

```
private static void SetText(TextBox textBox, string text)
    {
        textBox.Clear();
        textBox.AppendText(text);
        textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your binding is destroyed by setting a new value (which is strange, for a two way binding the binding should stay intact), then use ((TextBox)sender).SetCurrentValue(TextBox.TextProperty, newValue) to leave the binding intact.

Answer (score 1):

You don`t need to modify value of TextBox at all! In code you need only to modify your related value (*ShortCutText*) Also you can set **IsReadOnly**="**True**" property of your TextBox.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ShortCutText,Mode=OneWay}" 
         KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

You should realize *INotifyPropertyChanged* interface in your class as described in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Modify setter of your *ShortCutText* property (to which your *TextBox* is bound to):

```
class MyClass:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string shortCutText="Alt+A";
    public string ShortCutText
    {
         get { return shortCutText; } 
         set 
             { 
                  shortCutText=value; 
                  NotifyPropertyChanged("ShortCutText");
             }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void NotifyPropertyChanged( string props )
    {
        if( PropertyChanged != null ) 
            PropertyChanged( this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs( prop ) );
    }

}
```

WPF will subscribe to the PropertyChanged event automatically.
Now use **KeyDown** event of TextBox, for example, like this:

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown( object sender , KeyEventArgs e )
{
    ShortCutText = 
        ( e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown( Key.LeftCtrl )? "Ctrl+ " : "" )
        + e.Key.ToString( );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar case.

When I clear the textbox this losing the Binding.

I wore: `textbox1.Text = String.empty`

I change for this: `textbox1.Clear()`

And this is point for my solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM you should not change the Text property of the TextBox from code , change the value in the view model and the pattern will do its job synchronizing the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in the xaml itself:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ShortCutText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

> UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged