# Usercontrol binding lost on value updated, that doesn't happen with standard textbox control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

I have a problem with binding in usercontrol.

This is my usercontrol:

### UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-ompatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    x:Name="usercontrol"
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding HmiField, ElementName=usercontrol}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

### UserControl1.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {

        public double HmiField
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(HmiFieldProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HmiFieldProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HmiFieldProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("HmiField", typeof(double), typeof(UserControl1));

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the main window:

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Md, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <UniformGrid>
        <Button Content="{Binding Prop1}" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Prop1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
        <local:UserControl1 HmiField="{Binding Prop1}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApp1
{

    public class tMd: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Interfaccia INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

        #endregion

        private double prop1;
        public double Prop1 { get
            {
                return prop1;
            }
            set
            {
                if (prop1 != value)
                {
                    prop1 = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Prop1");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public tMd Md
        {
            get { return (tMd)GetValue(MdProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MdProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MdProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Md", typeof(tMd), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(new tMd()));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Md.Prop1 = 1234.5678;
        }
    }
}
```

I found some similar question:

[How do I change TextBox.Text without losing the binding in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280927/how-do-i-change-textbox-text-without-losing-the-binding-in-wpf)

[WPF: Binding is lost when bindings are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586924/wpf-binding-is-lost-when-bindings-are-updated)

[WPF Textbox TwoWay binding in datatemplate not updating the source even on LostFocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31109776/wpf-textbox-twoway-binding-in-datatemplate-not-updating-the-source-even-on-lostf)

But I can't completely understand what's happening: why a standard textbox work as expected and my usercontrol no?

Or better: is there a way to have my usercontrol works with the textbox's behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Your code seems to work the same for TextBox and UserControl1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binding must be TwoWay, either set explicitly

```
<local:UserControl1 HmiField="{Binding Prop1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

or implicitly by default:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HmiFieldProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(HmiField), typeof(double), typeof(UserControl1),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

A TextBox's `Text` property is registered like shown above, i.e. with the `BindsTwoWayByDefault` flag.

---

At the `TextBox` Binding in the UserControl's XAML you may also want to update the source property while the user is typing (instead of only on lost focus):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding HmiField,
                ElementName=usercontrol,
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

or without the otherwise useless generated `usercontrol` field:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding HmiField,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: So simple... so obvious! Thank you a lot Clemens! I was losing my eyes in [textbox's source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/TextBox.cs,47e834d7646f17c6,references) without seeing the evidence!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your Prop1 notifies when it changes, but you haven't told you binding to trigger on that notification.
Try including  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in you binding